# Print statement, spacing issue.

Tags: java, printf

I'm trying to create a text-based slot machine. However, when I print the variable "s1" "s2"or "s3", as you can see, everything comes out shifted. My problem is being caused by the fact that s1, could various lengths. I'm familiar with the printf concept, but im unsure how I could correct the spacing issue.

```
                  ("|=================================|     ____\n" +
                   "|           SLOT MACHINE          |    [    ]\n" +
                   "|=================================|     / /\n" +
                   "|                                 |    / /\n" +
                   "|    =========================    |   / /\n" +
                   "|    |   1   |   2   |   3   |    |  / /\n" +
                   "|    =========================    | / /\n" +
                   "|    |       |       |       |    |===|\n"+
                   "|    | "+s1+"| "+s2+"| "+s3+"|    |   |\n" +
                   "|    |       |       |       |    |===|\n" +
                   "|    =========================    |\n" +
                   "|                                 |\n" +
                   "|          [Insert Money]         |\n" +
                   "|=================================|" );
```

Output looks like this....

```
|=================================|     ____
|           SLOT MACHINE          |    [    ]
|=================================|     / /
|                                 |    / /
|    =========================    |   / /
|    |   1   |   2   |   3   |    |  / /
|    =========================    | / /
|    |       |       |       |    |===|
|    | Apple| Orange| Orange|    |   |
|    |       |       |       |    |===|
|    =========================    |
|                                 |
|          [Insert Money]         |
|=================================|
```

Comment: Pad the strings with `%Ns` for some value of N e.g. `%6s`.

Comment: `System.out.printf("|    |%7s|%7s|%7s|    |   |\n", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange");`

Comment: `System.out.println ("|    |%7s|%7s|%7s|    |   |".format (s1, "  Nut  ", "Banana", "Vanille"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with the following. Should work fine.

```
String slotMachine = "|=================================|     ____\n" +
                     "|           SLOT MACHINE          |    [    ]\n" +
                     "|=================================|     / /\n" +
                     "|                                 |    / /\n" +
                     "|    =========================    |   / /\n" +
                     "|    |   1   |   2   |   3   |    |  / /\n" +
                     "|    =========================    | / /\n" +
                     "|    |       |       |       |    |===|\n"+
                     "|    |%7s|%7s|%7s|    |   |\n" +
                     "|    |       |       |       |    |===|\n" +
                     "|    =========================    |\n" +
                     "|                                 |\n" +
                     "|          [Insert Money]         |\n" +
                     "|=================================|";
System.out.printf(slotMachine, "Apple", "Orange", "Orange");
```